# Сравнение строк в C++

Tags: c++

Задали сделать массив структур, в котором ведомости про поезда (по названиям переменных думаю всё понятно). Нужно чтобы программа выводила время отправления поездов + цену билетов на них при вводе пользователем города.

Не получается сравнить строку введённую пользователем с названием города в 21 строке
**(несовместимые типы операндов ("char" и "char *"))**

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct trains {
    char number[3];
    char destination[100];
    int time;
    float price;
};

void show(trains arr[], int, char);

void show(trains arr[], int n, char city) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char* gets (char *city);
        if (city == arr[i].destination) {
            cout << "Time:\t" << arr[i].time << '\n' << "Price:\t" << arr[i].price << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 5;
    char city[100];
    trains arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Train number: " << '\t\n';
        cin.getline(arr[i].number,3);
        cout << "Destination: " << '\t\n';
        cin.getline(arr[i].destination, 100);
        cout << "Time: " << '\t\n';
        cin >> arr[i].time;
        cout << "Price: " << '\t\n';
        cin >> arr[i].price;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что в коде делает это объявление - `char* gets (char *city);`?

Comment: Мешанина C и C++

Comment: Что означает параметр `char city` в `void show(trains arr[], int n, char city)`? Почему вы пытаетесь сравнивать его с `arr[i].destination`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну ошибка же явно говорит, в чем проблема: вы сравниваете символ типа `char` с указателем на `char`. Если у вас тег `c++`, почему бы не использовать везде `std::string`, заведомо не получая таких ошибок?